# Is it possible to extract specific data from Stackdriver log and use for a variable, if so how would i go about this?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, stackdriver

Im trying to extract the ids i highlighted in the picture attached for use on a next step, i have to extract the time_spent as well for other reasons which i should be able to figure out if i can just get the concept down of extracting specific data from a log. The full process will be pulling data from clickup, rearrange and place in last row of my time entry table in google sheets.

[Log question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PX37V.png)

Answer (score 1):

The Cloud Logging API can be used to retrieve Stackdriver logs.
You need to do multiple things in order to get it to work.

- Create a Google Cloud Platform Project
- Enable the Cloud Logging API for the Cloud Platform Project
- Associate the Cloud Platform Project with your Apps Script project
- Use the Cloud Logging REST API from Apps Script by using UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)
- Manually edit the Apps Script manifest file appsscript.json to include scopes for the cloud logging API and making an external request

### Manifest file - appsscript.json

```
{
  "timeZone": "GMT",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"]

}
```

This isn't exactly what you need, but I have some example code for downloading Stackdriver logs at GitHub.

[GitHub - Download Stackdriver logs to Google spreadsheet](https://github.com/Blueprinter/AppsScript-Download-StackDriver-Logs/blob/master/GS_Download_Logs)

In your case, it seems like you want to use Stackdriver as a temporary storage location to set and then immediately retrieve a user choice.
Stackdriver probably isn't the best solution for that situation.  If you need to send a user choice setting out to some external storage location, you'd probably be better off using a database.  You can use Firebase to send out a value from your client side user interface, save it to a database, then then retrieve it from somewhere else.  Firebase is good for doing this type of thing because it's fast, and made for situations like this.